# How to retrieve the shares of a status/photo with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know it's possible to retrieve the 'likes' of a picture or status, e.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/id_of_your_status_or_photo?access_token=...

Then I have some info like the likes and comments, but no share info

You can get some basic info from an url like https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com

But I would like to know how you get the information of the people who've shared your photo or status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer:

> But I would like to know how you get the information of the people
>   who've shared your photo or status.

You are not allowed to know this, that would be an invasion of privacy.  The closest you can do is to take an authenticated user's acess_token to your app and iterate thru their stream items until you find your link.

FYI, shares and likes are rolled up together into the like/share count.

Per the documentation:

> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> ```
> The number of likes of this URL
> The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.
> ```

Comment: yes, that's true, but sometimes i faced it once, it counted comments count twice. so be careful.

Comment: Facebook, as with any company that makes software, will inadvertently allow bugs to go into production.  Facebook probably has a higher bug ratio than other companies that employ a QA department to test (as well as have the balls to reject) software prior to release.